# Wordpress overwriting title in customized theme

Tags: regex, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm attempting to change the  of the Lightword theme to show only the page title in the  tag, and not the "Page Title | Blog Title" it normally does.

In the header template, I changed the title line to:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

After refreshing the page on the server, it STILL showed up as "Page Title | Blog Title". I went on to delete the title entirely as a test, leaving only `<title></title>` - but it appears something overrode it within WP, and the same title format came out.

Finally, I added a space in the title tag like such (designed to break any regexps):

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></ title>
```

And at long last, my title actually came out `<title>Page Title</ title>`. This behavior strikes me as extraordinarily odd, however - why does wordpress (or this theme) resist changing the title structure? Is there any less-hacky way to get around it?

Comment: <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title> works for me.

Comment: I'm not sure if this only happens with this particular theme - are you using Lightword?

Comment: Well, I still can't duplicate the problem with WP 3.1.2. Do you have any specal plugins installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead to show just the page title:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

### EDIT

Try this code to get just the page name in title:

```
<title><?php wp_title("",true); ?></title>
```

Comment: If I do <title><?php the_title(); ?>
</title> it STILL overwrites it.

Comment: Just for testing can you try changing to a different theme to make sure that is not a problem.

Comment: I just tried another theme, on a different server, and the exact same thing happened to me. This is in the latest version of Wordpress.

Comment: I added the answer in EDIT section, please try and let me know.

Comment: I don't think the title code has anything to do with it, nor the theme.

Comment: @Nano8Blazex: Please see this Wordpress reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title and see the example under **Turning Off »** Exactly what OP wanted to do.

Comment: Thats about turning off the >> mark. The OP wants to get rid of the Blog Title, and <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title> should work fine.

Comment: the ,true is default, anyways.